# When I Update child value is adding new child in firebase - ios

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to change the child value without create a new child using swift code and Firebase database

When I clicked on a button I tried to update `status` value from waiting to accepted

```
@IBAction func accept(_ sender: Any) {

    let values = ["status": "accepted"]
    Database.database().reference().root.child("specialCourses").childByAutoId().updateChildValues(values)

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NKZk.png)

[This picture contain created new child when pressing on "قبول"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NKZk.png)

[update code when clicking button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3PrO.png)

[the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIryG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call `childByAutoId()`, the database creates a new child node.

If you want to update an existing node, you must know its ID and then call:

```
Database.database().reference().root
    .child("specialCourses").child("idOfChildYouWantToUpdate").updateChildValues(values)
```

Since you're only updating a single field, you can also do this with:

```
Database.database().reference().root
    .child("specialCourses/idOfChildYouWantToUpdate/status").setValue("accepted")
```